# How to run a method in a new thread in Jscript .NET

Tags: .net, multithreading, jscript, jscript.net

I have been looking for an answer for 2 days now and I am truly stuck! I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474467/instantiating-a-system-threading-thread-object-in-jscript), but the answer did not work.

I have a jscript class, `WorkerClass` which has a function, `PerformCalculation`, that needs to run on a separate thread because it cannot run on the UI thread.

This is my solution:

**`CallerClass`**

```
private function PerformCalculation() {
    var workerClass = new WorkerClass(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3);
    var workDelegate : ThreadStart = new ThreadStart(workerClass.PerformCalculation);
    var workerThread : Thread = new Thread(workDelegate);
    workerThread.Start();
    workerThread.Join();
}
```

I have tried a few things, such as:

- Putting the `PerformCalculation` function in the `CallerClass`
- Putting the `PerformCalculation` function in a separate class, i.e. `WorkerClass`
- Making the `PerformCalculation` function `private`, `public`, `static` and with no access modifier (default)
- `var workerThread : Thread = new Thread(workerClass.PerformCalculation);`

In the first three scenarios, I got the following compile-time error:

```
Delegates should not be explicitly constructed, simply use the method name
```

and the last scenario gives the following compile-time error:

```
More than one constructor matches this argument list
```

What do you think is the problem with my code and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know the syntax of JScript.Net, but have you tried `var workDelegate : ThreadStart = workerClass.PerformCalculation;`?

Comment: Compiles fine @svick . I will try an run it. Thanks.

Comment: It definitely worked as needed @svick . Do you want to copy what you wrote above as an answer so I can designate it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error message says clearly what needs to be done: to construct a delegate, don't use `new`:

```
var workDelegate : ThreadStart = workerClass.PerformCalculation;
```