# Is there a way to declare a class inside a try and catch block in jscript?

Tags: multithreading, jscript.net

I want to use System.Threading methods provided by the .NET. for creating 2 test conditions that must happen simultaneously.

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474467/instantiating-a-system-threading-thread-object-in-jscript?noredirect=1&lq=1) solution to put the function in a class I was able to create 2 threads and run them parallely in jsc compiler.

But the environment I am writing my test scripts in, places my entire code in a try block and then compiles, which throws the

> error:JS1109: Class definition not allowed in this context.

Is there anyway to make multithreading possible without the use of classes in JScript?